# How to show VB application ONLY in system tray

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible that we can show application only in system tray(the tray at bottom right of screen) instead of , as normally application opens in bottom bar ? If yes then how can we do it in Visual Basic 2010 .

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you using? Windows Forms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: @dario_ramos : Windows Forms.

Comment: @ManasVerma Would you please consider to accept my answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266383

Answer (score 2):

There is a showInTaskbar property you can set to false on your windows form. Moreover you can set Visible to false.

In your Designer you can add a notifyIcon to your form, this is the typical tray icon you are searching for.